"Unable to install ng-apexcharts@1.7.6 with Angular 15 due to dependency conflict"
I am working on an Angular project with version 15.2.10, and I need to install the ng-apexcharts library, specifically version 1.7.6, to use ApexCharts in my application.
The Problem
When I try to install ng-apexcharts@1.7.6 using npm, I encounter a dependency conflict error.
The Error Message
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving: assess-web-app@9.1.46 npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.10 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.10" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^19.0.0" from ng-apexcharts@1.15.0 npm ERR! node_modules/ng-apexcharts npm ERR!   ng-apexcharts@"^1.7.7" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
I attempted to install the package using --force or --legacy-peer-deps, but I’m concerned about potential issues with this approach.
Verified the compatibility of Angular and ng-apexcharts versions in their respective documentation.
Tried locking ng-apexcharts to version 1.7.6, but it still raises a similar error.
I want to install ng-apexcharts@1.7.6 and use it in my Angular 15 project without dependency conflicts.
Environment
Angular CLI: 15.2.11
Node: 18.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2

try npm i ng-apexcharts@1.8.0 execute this in the folder where you have the package.json of your project

add to your package.json ng-apexcharts: 1.7.6 fixed to specific version. Possible problem is that you use caret in version (ng-apexcharts@"^1.7.7") so remove caret (^) and it should install correct 1.7.6 version without err.

@lukap123456 Thanks for the suggestion! Removing the caret (^) and specifying the exact version 1.7.6 in package.json worked like a charm. The installation went through without any issues, and everything is working as expected now. Appreciate your help!
